# Why my Struts 1 I18N could not locate the properties files?

Tags: java, internationalization, struts, struts-1

I am implementing a basic Struts 1 i18n web application and the expected output (`multi-language.jsp`) should be similar as screenshot below:

p.s. My project is only available in English & German, properties files are named as `Common.properties` & `Common_de.properties` respectively.

[image]

However, my application could not locate the properties files in project (located under `src/properties/$Common_CountryCode.properties$`). When I hit the application URL, console pops up some warnings:

```
Nov 15, 2018 4:45:20 PM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources loadLocale
WARNING:   Resource properties/Common_en_US.properties Not Found.
Nov 15, 2018 4:45:20 PM org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources loadLocale
WARNING:   Resource properties/Common_en.properties Not Found.
```

But the fact is my project doesn't even have these two properties file in it. And again, when I click the preferred language, console pops up some info (not sure if it matters) and browser will shows `404--Not Found`:

```
Nov 15, 2018 4:50:00 PM org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor init
INFO: Initializing composable request processor for module prefix ''
Nov 15, 2018 4:50:01 PM org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.CreateAction createAction
INFO: Initialize action of type: action.Action
```

This is my `struts-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" 
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
<struts-config>

    <form-beans>
        <form-bean
            name="userForm"
            type="form.Form"/>

    </form-beans>

    <action-mappings>

        <action
            path="/LoginPage"
            type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction"
            parameter="/WebRoot/multi-language.jsp"/>

        <action
            path="/Submit"
            type="action.Action"
            name="userForm"
            validate="true"
            input="/WebRoot/multi-language.jsp"
            >
            <forward name="success" path="/WebRoot/multi-language.jsp"/>
        </action>

        <action
            path="/Locale"
            type="action.Action"
            name="userForm"
            parameter="method"
            validate="false"
            >
            <forward name="success" path="/WebRoot/multi-language.jsp"/>
        </action>

    </action-mappings>

    <message-resources
        parameter="properties.Common" />

</struts-config>
```

The `multi-language.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>multi-language.jsp</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><bean:message key="label.common.message" /></h1>

<html:messages id="err_name" property="common.username.err">
<div style="color:red">
    <bean:write name="err_name" />
</div>
</html:messages>

<html:messages id="err_password" property="common.password.err">
<div style="color:red">
    <bean:write name="err_password" />
</div>
</html:messages>
<br />
<br />

<html:link page="/Locale.do?method=english">English</html:link>
<html:link page="/Locale.do?method=german">German</html:link>


<html:form action="/Submit">
<br />
<bean:message key="label.common.username" /> : <html:text property="username" />
<br />
<br />
<bean:message key="label.common.password" /> : <html:text property="password" />
<br />
<br />

<html:submit><bean:message key="label.common.button.submit" /></html:submit>
</html:form>


</body>
</html>
```

`Action.java` (controller)

```
package action;

import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.Globals;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction;

public class Action extends DispatchAction {

    public ActionForward german(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws Exception {

            request.getSession().setAttribute(
                    Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.GERMAN);

            return mapping.findForward("success");
        }

        public ActionForward english(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws Exception {

            request.getSession().setAttribute(
                    Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.ENGLISH);

            return mapping.findForward("success");
        }
}
```

`Form.java` (view)

```
package form;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;

public class Form extends ActionForm{
    String username;
    String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

        if( getUsername() == null || ("".equals(getUsername())))
        {
           errors.add("common.username.err",
            new ActionMessage("error.common.username.required"));
        }

        if( getPassword() == null || ("".equals(getPassword())))
        {
           errors.add("common.password.err",
            new ActionMessage("error.common.password.required"));
        }

        return errors;
    }

    @Override
    public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // reset properties
        username = "";
        password = "";
    }
}
```

Apologize if too much of code up here, just wanna makes the scenario clear.

Comment: "But the fact is my project doesn't even have these two properties file in it." Well... where are the property files you speak of then?

Comment: Only `Common.properties` & `Common_de.properties` for English and German language respectively under `src/properties/`.

Comment: Did you try putting the English properties in the file it's looking for them in?

Comment: `Common.properties` actually is the one for English properties. But then the console shows `xxx.properties` is missing (as stated in question) so I created it and leave it empty then put it together with other `.properties`. However I don't see this is the issue causing the `404--NotFound`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in your `struts-config.xml` should be something like this

```
  <message-resources parameter="Common" null="true" />
```

Then Struts 1 (Java) tries to resolve the [ResourceBundle Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s1804resourcebundleinheritance01.html) for your locale using `Common_en_US`, `Common_en` and `Common`. In the end, if no bundle is found, `MissingResourceException` is thrown.

The class responsible for loading of resources, `org.apache.struts.util.PropertyMessageResources`, replaces "." in

```
    <message-resources parameter="properties.Common" />
```

with "/" resulting in your warning *Resource properties/Common_en.properties Not Found* as ".properties" is being added automatically and "properties/" is added to the path. 


Assuming your files lie somewhere on the classpath, like `WEB-INF/classes`, Struts should be able to find them without warning once you correct the config.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Actually something was wrong with the overall project so I reconstructed it in a new web project. I put `*.properties` under a package named `properties` and define the parameter in `struts-config.xml` this way: `<message-resources parameter="properties/ApplicationResource" />`. Now it works as a charm. Thanks, though.

Comment: Glad it works now, you could use "properties.ApplicationResource" as well as mentioned.